# Orphan created by biblatex

Tags: biblatex, typography, widows-orphans

I have a footnote that ends with an awkward orphan.

[image]

The footnote is so long and the orphan so small that I would normally be able to fix this quite easily by pushing the orphan `12` back up on the preceding line with a non-breaking space character `~`.

But in this case the orphan is created by `biblatex`, and I have no idea how to remove an orphan created by it. I tried the only thing I could think of, which was to add `~` to the reference, i.e. `[~12]{elseth1982}`, but it has no effect. Is there any way I can fix this *locally* (i.e. without adding a non-breakable space before *all* page numbers in my citations)?

The relevant part of my document looks like this (it's not a MWE, so no need to try to compile it):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style = authoryear-comp]{biblatex}
\renewcommand{\postnotedelim}{\iffieldnums{postnote}{\addcolon\addspace}{\addspace}} % use colon with space before pages, but use just a space before citations that aren't pages (§, no., etc.)

\begin{document}
Text\footnote{Footnote text\parencites[3]{maageroe1978}[3]{maageroe1981}[33]{maageroe1983}[12]{elseth1982}.}
\end{document}
```

EDIT: The terminology confuses me here. I would've thought a single word on a line by itself at the end of a paragraph would be a widow (since it "has no future"), but [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Widows_and_orphans) calls it an orphan.

Comment: Have you tried `\enlargethispage{1\baselineskip}` just ahead of the command that creates the footnote?

Comment: @Mico Wouldn't that just allow one more line of body text before the footnote text? The footnote text itself wouldn't change by extending the bottom margin of the page.

Comment: What I have done so far (and which might be the best solution?) is to push a word earlier in the footnote one line up. I pushed the word `og` in the third to last line up, and that also removed the final orphan `12`.

Comment: Ah, I see now I got confused by the term "orphan". It usually involves a page break, but I now realize you're referring to a line break without a page break.

Comment: Try `\renewcommand{\postnotedelim}{\iffieldnums{postnote}{\addcolon\addnbspace}{\addspace}}`. The space inserted after the colon is currently breakable and we probably don't want that.

Comment: @moewe I'm worried about applying such global changes. I think it's ok to break the line before the page number in cases where further references are piling up after it. Or maybe I'm wrong. Do you know anything about typographic traditions regarding this?

Comment: @moewe How do I invite you to a chat about this ... ?

Comment: Now, If you are worried about applying this globally (why would you? it bothers you now, it will bother you again if it happens again), use `\AtNextCite{\renewcommand{\postnotedelim}{\iffieldnums{postnote}{\addcolon\addnbspace}{\add‌​space}}}` just before the offending citation. I would have thought it desirable to hold the page number to the colon in all cases with your layout, but then I'm not sure about conventions here. If there were a page prefix like "p." I wouldn't worry about the break too much, but here it just looks awkward.

Comment: @moewe It's not the line break before the page number that bothered me, it was the orphan. They just happened to coincide here. I've pondered before about disallowing line breaks for page number references, but I never reached a conclusion. If you'd like, you can see a number of such line breaks in [my document](http://folk.uio.no/sverrej/publication_files/inpress/bergen/stausland.johnsen_bergen.2015.pdf). Do you think it looks awkward?

Comment: To be honest, it wouldn't bother me here either. If it were pushed to another *page*, that would bother me. But here, I wouldn't be worried about it.

Comment: OK, but the way to get rid of the orphan here is to make the page number stick, I think. (It definitely seems the easiest here.) I have to say breaks don't look too bad, but I think I would still prefer the page number to stick, but then I'm not a professional when it comes to typographical subtleties such as this. (And another thing one should keep in mind is the repercussions from such a change: the lines in the example are quite short and taking away break points can have negative effects). If you don't already use the `microtype` package try that first, it can help with these troubles.

Comment: @cfr @moewe It's true that an orphan of this kind is the least bad variant among widows and orphans. My main motivation for fixing this orphan here is precisely because of its effects elsewhere (which are positive - it fixes a bad widow on another page). I'm using `microtype`.

Comment: Basically, I'm thinking that keeping it on the previous line may well cause an overly full box. But breaking before needs to push the whole `author year: pages` to the next line, which will surely cause the previous one to be filled too sparsely. If you change it globally, this may cause long author names to be pushed to the line below, creating even greater issues. But I'm not a professional typographer - maybe these breaks are simply unacceptable. (But what is the better option? Probably rewording.)

Comment: @cfr You can look at the result when applying the fix I mentioned in my second comment in this thread - in [this picture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/31Zq4.png). I think the biggest difference is in the second line, which might have had too much white space between words in the initial version. Are the characters too cramped now ... ? It's hard to judge.

Comment: @cfr & moewe What's looks better, [this output](http://i.stack.imgur.com/31Zq4.png) (my fix) or [this output](http://i.stack.imgur.com/O9Zdg.png) (moewe's fix)? For what it's worth, the former fixes a later widow issue, the latter doesn't.

Comment: I don't think it is good to split the citation label. It might be unavoidable sometimes, but I wouldn't do it to fix something else unless that was clearly worse. I prefer a break after the label and before the number than a mid-label break. But, as I say, I am not a typographer and me is ignorant ;).

Comment: I see, my solution just shifted the issue here. (To something not much better, maybe even worse.) So a non-`biblatex` solution is probably nicer.

Comment: @moewe I am making too much of this. What I'm trying now is to keep your solution, but then to look at the end of all paragraphs and fix those orphan lines which have 7 or fewer characters before the final period. Doing that also fixes an ugly widowed line I have later in the document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you seem to have a normal footnote you could try `\looseness-1` (it depends on the concrete text if it helps):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
Text\footnote{%
%\looseness-1 
Footnote text\lipsum*[1] text text text text12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12).}
\end{document}
```

### without `\looseness`

[image]

### with `\looseness`

[image]

Comment: But won't this push more onto the last line, so the widow elsewhere will be just as bad? That is, it may fix the line break issue in the footnote, but it won't fix the problem which avoiding that line break is supposed to solve? Or will this push enough to take up an additional line as well, which might, I suppose, solve the problem?

Comment: @cfr If it makes the footnote one line shorter, it will also fix the widow elsewhere, as making the footnote one line shorter will allow one more line of body text before the footnote. (Caveat - I don't know what `looseness` does).

Comment: @Sverre I may have misunderstood what it does. The screenshot made me think that it reduced the density per line, but perhaps it increases it, in which case you're right. I guess you can always try it ;).

Comment: @cfr: With \looseness TeX tries to make the paragraph shorter (or longer with a positive number) than the "natural" number of lines. But it won't do it if it doesn't work.

Comment: I've been reading in the TeXbook now, and I gather that how aggressive `\looseness` is will depend on the value of `\tolerance`, which is set by default to `200`. I have no idea what a good or bad tolerance is, so should I just leave `\tolerance` alone and conclude that `TeX` will apply `\looseness` appropriately (that is not too aggressively)?